# How to force `clang-format` to break constructor initializer when it doesn't exceed column limit?

Tags: c++, coding-style, clang-format

I'm encountering a coding style problem with `clang-format`. It seems to me that clang-format cannot break initializer list and its function body when it doesn't exceed the column limit.

So basically, this is the code I want:

```cpp
deque() 
: _start(), _finish(), _map(), _map_size() 
{ 
    _initialize_map(0); 
}
```

But clang format gives me this:

```cpp
deque() : _start(), _finish(), _map(), _map_size() { _initialize_map(0); }
```

There are some format that I'm satisfied with the same config. For example:

```cpp
explicit deque(size_type count, const value_type &value)
: _start(), _finish(), _map(), _map_size() // Initializers list on one new single line
{
    // Break function body
    _initialize_map(count);
    _fill_construct(value);
}
```

Here is my full `.clang-format`:

```yaml
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignArrayOfStructures: None
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled:         true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    true
AlignConsecutiveBitFields:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    false
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands:   Align
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: All
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: All
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
AttributeMacros:
  - __capability
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  false
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: Never
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile:     false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Always
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     80
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
QualifierAlignment: Leave
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 0
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DeriveLineEnding: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
PackConstructorInitializers: NextLine
BasedOnStyle:    ''
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IfMacros:
  - KJ_IF_MAYBE
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentRequiresClause: true
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
InsertBraces:    false
InsertTrailingCommas: None
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PointerAlignment: Right
PPIndentWidth:   -1
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
ReflowComments:  true
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
RequiresClausePosition: OwnLine
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Leave
ShortNamespaceLines: 1
SortIncludes:    CaseSensitive
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterIfMacros:   true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  AfterRequiresInClause: false
  AfterRequiresInExpression: false
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyBlock: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  Never
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum:         1
  Maximum:         -1
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
Standard:        Latest
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        8
UseCRLF:         false
UseTab:          Never
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - STRINGIZE
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
...
```

Any comment is appreciated. Thank you!

EDITED:

I know there is a configuration, `PackConstructorInitializer: BinPack`, that looks like to match with what I want. But somehow, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
PackConstructorInitializers: NextLine
```

with

```
PackConstructorInitializers: BinPack
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I forgot to mention this in my origin post.

Answer (score 0):

When you are satisfied with the default formatting but want to override it for specific cases, and don't want to surround your code with `/* clang-format off */` and `/* clang-format on */` comments, sometimes adding empty trailing comments to force line breaks can achieve the desired result.

Try something like this:

```cpp
deque() //
: _start(), _finish(), _map(), _map_size() 
{ 
    _initialize_map(0); 
}
```